# Markov chain in a closed interval

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, stationary-processes

Let $I=[0,1]$, $\varepsilon>0$ and $(X_n)$ of i.i.d. random variables (copies of X, with $supp(X)\subseteq (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ and $\mathbb E(X)>0$). Now, for each $\lambda>0$, we define the markov proces $Y^\lambda$ as:

\begin{equation}
Y^\lambda_n = \begin{cases}Y^\lambda_{n-1}+\lambda X_n,\text{ if } Y_{n-1}+\lambda X_n\in[0,1],\\
                   1,\text{ if } Y^\lambda_{n-1}+\lambda X_n>1,\\
                   0, \text{ if } Y^\lambda_{n-1}+\lambda X_n<0.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
and $Y_0=0$ almost surely.
More informally, that is, we consider the random walk in the interval $I$ with random variable $X$, but if the random walk surpasses the boundaries, it stays in the boundary.

$\textbf{Questions}$:

- Are the markov process $Y^\lambda$ Ergodic? That is, do these markov chains have an stationary distribution $\pi^\lambda$.
- If so, does it hold $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow0}\pi^\lambda([0,1))=0$?

**Intuition**:

- I think that the first point should follow from Krylov-Bogolioubov theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krylov%E2%80%93Bogolyubov_theorem).
- We can consider the following sequence of Markov chains:

\begin{equation}
\overline{Y}^\lambda_n = \begin{cases}\overline{Y}_{n-1}+\lambda X_n,\text{ if } \overline{Y}^\lambda_{n-1}+\lambda X_n\in[0,1],\\
                   1, \text{ if } \overline{Y}^\lambda_{n-1}+\lambda X_n>1.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Since the support of $X$ is bounded, we have that $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow0^+}\Pr[|Y^\lambda_n-\overline{Y}^ \lambda_n|>\delta]\rightarrow 0$ for all $\delta>0$. Moreover, since the expectancy is positive, we have that $\{\overline{Y}^\lambda_n\}$ has a stationary distribution $\overline{\pi}^\lambda$. My intuition here, is that with sufficient good conditions we should have that $\overline{\pi}^\lambda$ and $\pi^\lambda$ converge to the same distribution. And we can reduce the problem to $\{\overline{Y}^ \lambda_n\}$.

Comment: Please add your attempts at solving these

Comment: The assumptions are incomplete and not clear. One need a starting point $Y_0$. What are the assumptions on $Y_0$ ? Does the recursion formula involve always the same random variable $X$? If yes, you have not a Markov chain. The usual situation which yields Markov chains is a recursion governed by some sequence $(X_n)_{n \ge 1}$ of i.i.d. random variables (copies of $X$) which is independent of $Y_0$. In your situation, it would be $Y_n = ((Y_{n-1} + \lambda X_n) \vee 0) \wedge 1$.

Comment: The first element $Y_0$ can be any point of the interval. I see what you mean. Yes they are  recursion governed by some sequence $(X_n)$ of i.i.d. random variables (copies of $X$)